# subtract N minutes from rails datetime object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, time, timezone

I have a datetime field start_at which has the the date and time. How can I subtract 5 minutes from that?

Right now I'm doing `@schedule_time = @event.start_at - (@event.alert_before_min/1440.0)` but that always just subtracts 1 second from the time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`@event.start_at - some_count.minutes` will always work within Rails. There's also `seconds`, `hours`, `days`, `weeks`, `months`, and `years`.

Comment: A number of your choosing.